# .htaccess filter sub directory through index.php script

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-headers

I have folder of uploaded files, and I need a sub directory within it to be a protected directory and check user permissions each time one of its files are called.  .htaccess would call an index.php file in the uploaded_files directory while maintaining the URL so that the index.php can check the file against the database in order see if a logged-in user has access permissions for the file, if they do, the index.php will serve-up the file and the user would have no idea of the permission check.

I have actually made this work on my development server using the following code in my .htaccess in the uploaded files directory itself,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^protected($|/) - [F]

ErrorDocument 404 /uploaded_files/index.php
ErrorDocument 403 /uploaded_files/index.php
ErrorDocument 405 /uploaded_files/index.php
```

but on the live server, something is causing theese php headers to be ignored:

```
header('Content-Type: some/mime');
```

and/or

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="somefile.txt"');
```

I think it could be the forced 403 of the RewriteRule, but I'm using that so that the URL will not change and the index.php can get $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

I'm also filerting 404s through the index.php

Comment: Why don't you just move the protected files out of the web-root, rewrite everything to `index.php` and do the error handling in the php script?

Comment: It's a small reusable CMS that won't always be able to leave the webroot.  That, and I'm trying to adapt the exisiting system which manages the files in the uploaded_files folder via the Admin.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.  A redirect to  /uploaded_files.index.php and a L [Last] flag on the RewriteRule instead of the F [403] flag

RewriteEngine on
<strike>RewriteRule ^protected($|/) - [F]</strike>
RewriteRule ^protected($|/) /upload_files/index.php [L]


ErrorDocument 404 /uploaded_files/index.php
ErrorDocument 403 /uploaded_files/index.php
ErrorDocument 405 /uploaded_files/index.php